# Dual-booting Chrome OS and Ubuntu 13.04 on a PC

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 13.04, chromeos

Is it possible to install Chrome OS and Ubuntu 13.04 on a x86 System (Core 2 Duo)?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some general steps to take to dual boot Chrome OS and Ubuntu 13.04. I am also including some steps if you would like Windows on here as well.

### Install Ubuntu First

Before installing Ubuntu, make a clean MSDOS Partition table. You should be able to do this with gparted in Ubuntu (Go to Dash and search for it). When installing Ubuntu, make sure to select "Something Else". (**If you want Windows, for your partitions, parition a drive for Windows, but do not use /dev/sda1)**

### Install Chromium OS Second

When installing Chromium OS, install to a USB first, and then copy the contents of the USB through gparted in Ubuntu to the hard drive. Make sure to put the partition (C-STATE) on /dev/sda

### Install Windows Third (if triple booting)

Install Windows to whatever partition you made when installing Ubuntu earlier.

### Final Steps

**Boot into live Ubuntu and re-install grub. Do not boot into the Ubuntu that you installed.**

Lastly, boot into Ubuntu on the hard drive and run `sudo update-grub` in Terminal.

When you restart, you should see the two (or three) operating systems that you installed in the boot loader.

Comment: the steps are for clean installataion..i have an existing ubuntu installed and there's unallocated partition in the disk..can't i just squeeze in chromeOS on the unallocated partion without the need of making a clean partition table?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not installing clean, and want to Install Chrome OS AFTER you have installed Ubuntu, you can follow the steps as shown here

http://blog.championswimmer.in/2016/01/multibooting-chrome-os-on-your-laptop

Bascially you need two partitions - ROOT-A, 2.15GB ext2 and STATE 4GB or more - ext3/ext4

Copy the contents of the ROOT-A and STATE partitions of your Live USB (using `dd` to the corresponding partitions on your Hard disk, and run `update-grub2`

You need to edit the value of STATE_DEV in `/sbin/chromeos_startup` in your ROOT-A partition to make it point to a device other than /dev/sda1