# Installing OSes on Extended Partition

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, chromium

I've been trying to triple boot my laptop with a single HDD. An Ubuntu+Windows+Chromium OS is what I want.
Now, I think my problem is a bit deep and tricky, but I'd really like you guys to help me in anyway you can.

So here it is. I'm having trouble installing Windows to a GPT type partition table, which means I have to stick to the MBR type. Unfortunately, it only allows 4 primary partitions, or 3 primary + 1 extended partition.
I know I can install Ubuntu, as well as Windows to logical partitions. I'm not sure about whether Chrome OS can be run from logical partitions.

My problem would probably be solved if I'm able to run Chrome OS from logical partitions. I'll have to keep 1 primary partition as System Reserved in order for Windows to boot normally. Out of the 2 primary partitions left if I choose this case, both of them will go for Chrome OS if it's not possible to install it to logical partitions. [Chrome OS needs at least 2 partitions to run, at least that's what I found out of my week long research. ]

I read the answer in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319427/dual-booting-chrome-os-and-ubuntu-13-04-on-a-pc), and I feel it's kinda incomplete. The answerer hasn't addressed the second partition needed by Chromium. Neither has he addressed the swap partition needed by Ubuntu. If this answer is considered, 5 primary partitions would be needed at the least. Which ain't possible with MBR.
Can anyone here help me with my problem please? I'd really appreciate your help. :)

Comment: your problem will be solved if you correctly partition the drive.Upload gparted screenshot i will try to help you.

Comment: @AvinashRaj don't have gparted at the moment, because I'm running Ubuntu off a LiveUSB. Also, all of my disk space is unallocated. Nonetheless, here's my screenshot from disk utility.
http://s28.postimg.org/gf8eaxtrx/Screenshot_from_2013_12_11_16_54_33.png

Comment: plz install gparted by running this commands `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install gparted`,then upload its screenshot.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I don't understand what difference it'd make since my HDD space is fully un-allocated right now. Also I tried running those commands, but I run into errors, so I'm unable to do so. I can't see any difference it'd make though.

Comment: what errors did you face?did you connect to the internet?

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Windows, which will occupy the first 2 primary partitions, use its Disk Management tool to reduce Windows partition as desired, and create a "Recovery Disk" under Windows.
2. Boot your computer from live Ubuntu disk, start GParted, delete the "System Reserved" partition and grow the Windows to the right, to take up the empty space left by the "System Reserved" partition.
3. Restart your computer and if Windows fails to boot, repair using the Windows Recovery Disk. (NB: I tested this successfully with Windows 7 only.)
4. Boot your computer from live Ubuntu disk again, start GParted, create 2 primary partitions for Chrome OS, and then create a 4th Extended Partition, which may contain, for example, a partition for Ubuntu /root, a partition for /home and a swap partition.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'll try this ASAP, and get back to you.
Also, I read somewhere that if the Windows partition is marked as active before the installation gets completed, a new System Reserved partition isn't created. But anyway, I'll still try your method out.

Comment: @Kartik: Perhaps you can first try and create an approx. 20GB primary partition marked active (and no other partition) and see if Windows installs without creating "System Reserved" partition.